# Error loading aspx page: Only part of webpage displays correctly after loading the page for the 2nd time in an active session

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have an aspx page, which has a main display view and a form view. The main view is supposed to display a set of records and have a button (which redirects to the form) to add a new record. If I add a new record for the first time, it all happens smoothly and the main display view too (a Grid View) binds properly and populates everything.

I have a cancel button in the form view. Basically, if the user wants to go back to the display view after adding a new record, he clicks on Cancel to do so. After clicking cancel, and on trying to add a new record again, it does take me to the form view but displays only a part of the page. It doesn't load the master page, doesn't show some controls, shows some controls, etc. This is weird.

I have a data access layer, business object layer and my project layer. During the page rendering, the data access layer's Gateway function gets called to populate grid views, drop downs, etc. While debugging, I noticed that this doesn't happen for the second time. For the first time, everything gets called and loads properly, not when I do it for the second time or subsequent time **in one active session.**

Note: **Please note that everything is fine until I save a New Record, click Cancel to go back to the main view, then again trying to add a new record. If in the form view I try to add multiple records at the same time, even that works.**

Comment: sounds related to the cancel button and "going back". how are you doing that? maybe "go forward" to the main view so it's a brand new load? (just go to the page, as if for the first time.)

Comment: Any relevant code would be nice to see.  Also, I recommend breaking your question into paragraphs for easier readability.

Comment: @wazz: So, after a lot of debugging, I could solve the issue, though I do not know why the problem was actually occuring.

After clicking on the Cancel button, I used to hide the relevant controls and show the relevant ones, and then if the user Clicks on Add again, the relevant controls would be shown and hidden respectively.

Instead of that, if the user clicks on Cancel, I used Response.Redirect to the same page, so that it again brings it back to its initial state. After that, the problem went away :)

If any of you do know why I need to reload it entirely, please let me know. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Response.Redirect() rather than hiding/un-hiding controls did the trick for me.